# How to protect internal statistics API from users calling it over and over. PHP, LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, api, security

What would be a mechanism to protect an internal API endpoint that is being called using POST by frontend during some user interaction?

This API is used for statistics and is called for both logged in and guest users in the background.

How can I keep user from just clicking "Resend" from the network tab on that request?

Thank you.

(I'm using laravel, but general idea on what to implement here would be appreciated.)

Comment: What generates this invitation? Doesn't this API go through username/password authentication?

Comment: Add CSRF protection or require session-based authentication to secure the API endpoint from unauthorized access, including preventing users from clicking "Resend" from the network tab on that request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are searching for an API rate limit you can explore the full docs from here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting